# Authors, Articles, Magazines relationship in Relational Database [Doctrine]

Tags: sql, database-design, orm, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I have following entities:

**Author**: Id, Name

**Article**: Id, Title, Contents, Magazine_Id

**AuthorArticle**: Author_Id, Article_Id

**Magazine**: Id, Title

Author - Article is Many to Many.

What is the most efficient way to get the list of all the Magazines in which the Author's articles were published knowing the Author.Id.

Are there better design options than this??

**Currently I first select all the Articles and the Select DISTINCT Magazine_ID from them.**

I am using Symfony2 and Doctrine so any specific things are also welcome.

Comment: "Are there better design options than this?", not common sence, I would prefere to use an equal name for primary|forein KEYS, like aut_id in all tables, articel_id in all Tables ansd so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in one select:

```
 Select distinct m.title from
    author, 
    AuthorArticle, 
    Article, 
    Magazine 
 where 
    author.id = AuthorArticle.Author_Id
 and
    Article.id = AuthorArticle.Article_Id 
 and
    Magazine.id = Article.Magazine_Id
 and -- at least
    Author.id ='my id'
```

EDIT/APPEND (Are there better design options than this?)

the design is ok, if an artikel can have more than one autor

And as a naming design suggestion:

name your key equal, ie:

```
Author: author_ , Name
Article: artikel_, Title, Contents, Magazine_
AuthorArticle: Author_, Article_
Magazine: Magazine_, Title
```

this helps you prevent typos and selecting wrong ids with each other, you would get an error when selecting `author_` from `magazine`, but not if you just join `id`